# Does calling ToList multiple times effect performance?

Tags: c#, linq

I often times see that calling ToList will make query get executed every time. I'm a little confused about that. So in this scenario, would calling ToList the second time make the query get executed more than once? In what scenarios does the query get execute more than once?

```
//This gets from database and ToList is already called here
List<Customer> Customers = GetCustomersFromDataBase();

//ToList is called here again
List<Customer> FilteredCustomers = (from c in Customerswhere c.id == 1c).ToList();
```

Edit

I just provided this code example to understand what ToList really does. I'm not implementing it this way.
Also, I make a stored procedure call to return customers from db and create a list of customers from the returned datatable.

Comment: Why do you want to? Rather store the list after calling ToList() and use it?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Are you doing to List() on the list again or on the IQueryable?

Comment: It is the LINQ _query_ (`IQueryable`) rather than a collection (`IEnumerable`) that may be evaluated many times (with a potential and significant performance hit) if referred to more than once in your code if you don't perform say a `.ToList()`.  This may depend on the LINQ provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `ToList` (or `ToArray`, `AsEnumerable`, etc) on an `IQueryable` will execute the query.  After that any LINQ expression you use will be operating on the in-memory list.

For instance, your code:

```
List<Customer> Customers = GetCustomersFromDataBase();
```

This will result in a `List` of `Customer` objects which represent the database records.  The list is now independent of the query used to fetch the results from the database, although linked records in the `Customer` objects will still need to be fetched from the database.

Then when you do this:

```
List<Customer> FilteredCustomers = (from c in Customers where c.id == 1c).ToList();
```

This is not operating on the database but on the results in memory that were returned from the previous statement.  In this case you will not be querying the database multiple times.

Where it *does* impact performance is when you have an `IQueryable` object that you call `ToList` on directly multiple times.  Each call to `ToList` on an `IQueryable` will result in a call to the database, with all of the attendant object tracking and such in the background.  Generally this is something you want to avoid, although additional filtering of the query prior to enumerating the results may result in better performance if the total number of records selected by the query is large and the filters pull small subsets of the data.

Comment: Your answer seems to make sense! One thing  I would want to double check - If I had a wcf service which returned IQueryable of customers, would that call that service every time I call ToList?

Comment: If you call `ToList` to get the content then you can call `ToList` on that result without invoking the WCF query again.  If you call `ToList` on the WCF `IQueryable` it will call the WCF service again to get the results.

Comment: In other words, if the target of the call is an `IQueryable` then it's going to query they (database|WCF service|whatever).  If it's a local collection then no query to the (database/WCF/etc).

Comment: The Reason I was asking was because I have a wcf service and I'm trying to not call the service more than once. I do bunch of filtering before I call ToList. That works, but later on depending on user selection, I would have to filter the results further and call the ToList again. That for some reason is making the service call again even though it's an in-memory object already.

Comment: @user3587180 - You say "That for some reason is making the service call again even though it's an in-memory object already", but that's not right. If it's an in-memory object it **wouldn't** make a service call.

Comment: You're incorrect on `AsEnumerable`; it doesn't execute the query, but it does mean that when the query is executed the part of it after the `AsEnumerable` call is executed by linq-to-objects rather than the query provider executing the rest.

Comment: What about a method of type `IEnumerable<T>` that returns a `ToList`, that is then transformed again with `ToList`?
i.e: `GetCustomers().ToList()` - So in effect: `.ToList().ToList()` or even: `.ToList().ToList().ToList().ToList()`

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Calling `ToList` on an object that is already a `List` will simply return the object, so not much in the way of overhead there.  A few cycles for the type check is all.

Answer (score 4):

In your scenario the query only get executed once.

Here:

```
List<Customer> FilteredCustomers = (from c in Customers where c.id == 1c).ToList();
```

This line only filter based on the variable `Customers`, which is a copy of the customer table populated by `ToList()`.

Comment: Whilst a fine answer on its own, it doesn't address _"So in this scenario, would calling ToList the **second time** make the query get executed more than once? **In what scenarios** does the query get execute more than once?
"_

Answer (score 3):

Check the source code for Enumerable.ToList() (google for it)
[Enumerable.ToList()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

So yes ToList().ToList(), is a waste, a **new** List is created, all (references to) elements in the first ToList are copied in the second one, causing new memory to be allocated and the first list is garbage collected, causing memory to be freed.