# Using Entity framework Include query is running extremely slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have class `ProcessMessage` and `ProcessMessage` detail. There is 1 to many relationship , 1 `ProcessMessage` can have many `ProcessMessageDetail`. I have written the code using Entity Framework 6 but its running extremely slow.

Any tips for optimizing it? If you see its at step 3,  I am using `ToList()`. Step 1 and step 2 is an `IQueryable`.

```
// 1
var query =  UnitOfWorkAsync.Repository<ProcessMessage>()
                            .Queryable()
                            .Include(x => x.ProcessMessages)                     
                            .Include(x => x.TestDetail)
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .AsExpandable()
                            .Where(Query(loggedProcess, status))
                            .Take(1000)
                            .AsQueryable();   

// 2        
query = query.OrderBy(sortBy + (reverse ? " descending" : "")).AsQueryable();


// 3  
return query
    .ToList()
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();


public class ProcessMessage
{
    public ProcessMessage()
    {
        ProcessMessages = new List<ProcessMessageDetail>();
    }
    public int ProcessMessageId { get; set; }
    public int? LoggedProcessId { get; set; }
    public int? ProcessMessageTypeId { get; set; }  
    public virtual LoggedProcess LoggedProcess { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<ProcessMessageDetail> ProcessMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `ToList()` before `Skip()` and `Take()` really jumps out at me, since `ToList()` will return a list with **all** data at that point.  The paging will happen in memory, rather than in sql.

Comment: I'm also not sure you need all those `AsQueryable` calls, but I don't think they will affect performance.

Comment: Also, You are doing your `OrderBy` wrong for descending items.  To get a descending sort use `OrderByDescending` instead.

Comment: Processmessagedetails have lots of records in it (10k+). 1 PM can have 10 processmessagedetail. I have added appropriate index

Comment: An index should have already been created for that automatically if the Foreign Key was set up correctly.

Comment: I updated the code , still taking 1 min to execute                                     var query =  UnitOfWorkAsync.Repository<ProcessMessage>().Queryable().Include(x=>x.ProcessMessages)                      (x=>x.TestDetail)
                 .AsNoTracking().AsExpandable()
                 .Where(Query(loggedProcess,status)).Take(1000).AsQueryable();   




// 3  
return query
    .ToList();

Comment: no need also for all of the Queryable stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely culprit is the first ToList in step three.

```
// 3  
return query
    //.ToList() //This will cause performance issues
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Check here for an explanation: [Does calling ToList multiple times effect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428642/does-calling-tolist-multiple-times-effect-performance)

There might also be issues with Skip and Take if you're too far from the first pages, check this: [Entity Framerowk Skip/Take is very slow when number to skip is big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531818/entity-framerowk-skip-take-is-very-slow-when-number-to-skip-is-big)

Comment: This is definitely the answer, you're storing all of the results from your data store into memory, instead of offloading it to the data store, then filtering the collection, and then converting your List into an IEnumerable<T>.